# Custom Eclipse Shortcuts Within Views

Tags: eclipse, pipeline, hotkeys, webmethods

[image: Pipeline View - Link Variables]

I want to create a shortcut for creating a link between two variables in my pipeline view.

Can someone tell me how (or if it is possible) to create a shortcut to this button?
When I look in `Preferences > General > Keys`, I can not find this function.

I am using Software AG webMethods Designer 8.2

Comment: show your plugin.xml content for this view.

Comment: where would i find plugin.xml?

Comment: Did you resolve that problem? How did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, you want to create a kind of button, using which you will be able to create link between two variables in pipeline ?
If yes, Then I think that is not possible.

Comment: the button outlined in red in the image links two items in the pipeline. I am wondering if I can create a keyboard shortcut to do this function instead of having to click the button.  (There was a keyboard shortcut in the previous software AG developer)